# How to debug a JOption error message in Java?

Tags: java, swing, exception, joptionpane, numberformatexception

I am doing a school management system project, everything is good except when I try to click the save button it returns the JOption error message that phone must be integer although it is already. I must say I have a similar form for teacher registration and that one works. How can it be?

```
private void jButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
try{    
        int day = Integer.valueOf((String)jComboBoxDay.getSelectedItem());
        int month = Integer.valueOf((String)jComboBoxMonth.getSelectedItem());
        int year = Integer.valueOf((String)jComboBoxYear.getSelectedItem());
        String birthDate = ""+day+month+year;
        String firstName = jTextFieldFirstName.getText();            
        String lastName = jTextFieldLastName.getText();
        String address = jTextFieldAddress.getText();
        String email = jTextFieldEmail.getText();
        int phoneNumber = Integer.parseInt((jTextFieldPhoneNumber).getText());
        String gender = (String)jComboBoxGender.getSelectedItem(); 
        String religion = jTextFieldReligion.getText();
        String contactTeacher =jTextFieldContactTeacher.getText();
        int contactPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt((jTextFieldContactPhoneNumber).getText());
        int momID = Integer.parseInt((jTextFieldMotherID).getText());
        int fatherID = Integer.parseInt((jTextFieldFatherID).getText());

        Reset();
            Students student = new Students(birthDate,firstName,lastName,address, email,phoneNumber,gender,religion,contactTeacher,contactPhoneNumber,momID,fatherID);
            studentsControl.createStudents(student);
            loadTable();
    } 
            catch (NumberFormatException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Phone must be an integer ","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jTextFieldPhoneNumber.setText("");
}
}
```

Comment: Well we can't actually tell where the error is because it could be a format exception from any of those fields.

Comment: Try printing the stack trace and look up if it's really the phone number. Your error message is hardcoded without any connection to reality...

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 4) To expand on the last comment, I mean the output of changing `catch (NumberFormatException exception)
    {` **to** `catch (NumberFormatException exception)
    { exception.printStackTrace();`

Comment: i tried the stack trace and i got the error, if i understand it right i should just paste it? what i don't understand is why an exactly similar form works for teacher registration and  the phone number is an attribute inherited by both teacher and student classes.

Comment: What happens if `day`, `month` or `year` fail to parse?  What amount `monID` or `fatherID `?  It's impossible for use to debug your code without more details

Comment: I have tried also with int birthDate = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldBirthDate.getText()); because maybe there was an error when selecting the item from the combobox. Needless to say that i have redone the studentsMapper,studentsController,studentsTableModel and even the registration form 3 times now... always getting that ridiculous error, but than again i have 2 other forms for parents and teachers which work, built on identical algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `month` description from `jComboBoxMonth` object.

Try getting the index instead by calling `getSelectedItem` method and adding `1`.